# Set deleted records = 1 without actually deleting the records

Tags: yii, cgridview

How can i set the records i want to delete to 1 instead of deleting the record itself? I am using Yii framework right now and i am new to it. I have the CGridview with update, view and delete. On the delete i want the user to set the records which they want to delete to 1, instead of deleting the entire record. Thank you in advance for any help you may provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your `actionDelete` in the controller:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);
        $model->is_deleted = "1"; //assuming is_deleted is the column name
        $model->update();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

and your model `search` function to remove those items which have `is_deleted = 1`, you can:

```
//.... rest of your code above
$criteria->addCondition("is_deleted != 1");
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
```

Comment: it is giving an error when i try to delete it. do i have to create a new function in the model also?

Comment: @revuer1 No, you don't have to create a function in your model. What exactly is your error?

Comment: this worked. Thank you. is there anyway i can change the color for the records from blue to red for the ones that says IsDeleted=1?

Comment: @revuer1 Glad it helped, please accept the answer if it has helped you. For the second part, it will be better if you ask a new question.